# How to delete previous points while plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization

I am plotting live data: for the plotting, I am using the line function, which improved the plotting performance a lot compared when using the plot function. Still, the plot gets slower with time. I realized that the sample points that I am creating are plotted, but even when they are not visible later the still remain in the plot. Could this cause any performance degradation?

I just want to see the sample points of the current three seconds, if use clf or cla function, just see very small part of the signal, which is not helpful for me. Do you have any suggestions?

```
%% opening function:

handles.figureHandle=figure;
guidata(hObject, handles);
t=1/200; %sample rate 5ms

%% button function:

if 40< newSamples
figure(handles.figureHandle)
              t = max(t) + (1:size(sample,1)) * 1/200;
              for x=1:8
                  subplot(8,8,x);
                  hold on
                  line('XDATA',t,'YDATA',sample(:,x),'MarkerSize', 1,'Color','r');
                  ylim([0 1024]);
                  xlim([max(t)-1 max(t)+2]);
                  hold off
              end


drawnow ;
      end
```

Update

```
%% opening function
sample=[];
t=[];
handles.figureHandle
for i=1:8
    subplot(2,2,i);
    hold on
    h=line(t,sample,'MarkerSize', 1,'Color','r');
    %          ylim([0 1024]);
    %          xlim([max(t)-1 max(t)+2]);
    hold off
end

t=1/200;
%% button function
figure(handles.figureHandle)
t = get(gca, 'XData');
sample = get(gca, 'YData');

t = max(t) + (1:size(sample,1)) * 1/200;
for x=1:8
    set(h,'XData',t,'YData',sample(:,x));
end
```

Comment: Rather than creating new plot objects every time, simply update the `XData` and `YData` properties of the existing plot object.

Comment: So basically I create the subplots in the opening function of the GUI and then in the button function I update the data?

Comment: Precisely. Create the plots once, and then update them. This will improve the performance significantly.

Comment: I have changed the code  (see updated post)but i get the error that XDATA property on the x-axes is not found

Comment: Please edit your question rather than trying to post code in a comment

Comment: I have added the code to the original post

Comment: You want `h` to point to the `line` object *not* the `subplot` objects

Comment: thank you! is there anything else that can be changed because the error is still occurring

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: error: 'There is no XData property on the Axes class.'
 for get(gcf, 'XData');
There is no XData property on the Figure class.'

Comment: Can you update your post with the modification that I recommended in my last comment?